# update column table with value of column from table b if it contains substring from another column from table b

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-9.5

There are 2 table like below:

```
Table a                        Table b

country_name                   id | string_bone   | country_name
------------------------       ---+---------------+---------------
usa                            1  | usa           | united states  
u s a                          2  | u s a         | united states
united states of america       3  | america       | united states
america                        4  | ...           | ...
```

I need to update `table_a.country_name` with `table_b.country_name` if `table_b.string_bone` is contained in `table_a.country_name`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET country_name = b.country_name
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT country_name
              FROM table_b
              WHERE a.country_name LIKE '%' || string_bone || '%') b;
```

I would like `table_a` to look like this after the update:

```
Table a                        

country_name                   
------------------------       
united states                            
united states                          
united states      
united states
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=01079ca8b2a4ea222a5b27280f4aeea2) the dbfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's easy to implement this requirement, like below:

```
update table_a a set country_name = b.country_name from table_b b where a.country_name ~ b.country_name;
```

The data example as below:

```
postgres=# select * from table_a;
       country_name       
--------------------------
 usa
 u s a
 united states of america
 america
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from table_b;
 country_name 
--------------
 america
 usa
 u s a
(3 rows)

postgres=# update table_a a set country_name = b.country_name from table_b b where a.country_name ~ b.country_name;
UPDATE 4
postgres=# select * from table_a;
 country_name 
--------------
 usa
 u s a
 america
 america
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I guess you meant `a.country_name ~ b.string_bone;` anyways I get `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "b" LINE 4: where a.country_name ~ b.string_bone;` See link of the dbfiddle - it's up to date.

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot. Sometimes i just don't see the most simple solution.

Comment: Welcome, give me a vote up and accept the answer please. Thanks :).

Comment: Sure! I was just waiting for the time to elapse :D

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE table_a a
    SET country_name = b.country_name
    from table_a t
    inner join table_b b
    on t.country_name LIKE '%' || b.string_bone || '%';
```